# How to algebraically calculate exact value of a trig function applied to any non-transcendental angle?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, angle

I looked around quite a bit here on StackExchange and elsewhere and couldn't find an answer to my specific question, so here goes.

How can you algebraically calculate the *exact* value of a trig function applied to a *non-transcendental* angle value? I know that for certain angles (e.g. 75°), you can represent them as a sum/difference of two angles with nice, algebraic trig function results (in this case, 75° = 30° + 45°). But what about a less convenient angle, for example something like sin(63°)?

**Some disclaimers/stipulations:**

I'm working with degrees here because I know that you run into transcendental results when working with radians, e.g., sin(1 rad). I'm also trying to stay in the realm of trigonometric functions only, not that I can really see how complex numbers or exponentials would help here (aside from identities), though I suppose that is why I'm asking for help. I know some angles (e.g. 36°) have polygonal geometric proofs, but that's not really what I'm looking for either. I would prefer to formulate the problem purely in terms of equations. Finally, I am trying to use finite math only; I know I could use Taylor series expansions to do this, but that won't give me the nice closed-form solution I'm after.

---

I saw an example online where the angle in question is an integer factor of one of the more common angles (e.g. [18° which is $\frac{90°}{5}$](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-value-of-sin18%C2%B0-1)), so I tried a similar approach for 63° and got nowhere. Here is (roughly) my attempt:

**Calculating sin(63°):**

$\mathrm{sin(63°)} = \mathrm{sin(3° + 60°)} = \mathrm{sin(3°)cos(60°) + sin(60°)cos(3°)}$

**Calculating sin(3°):**

Let $\theta = 3°$

$10\theta = 30°, 5\theta=30° - 5\theta, \mathrm{sin(5\theta)} = \mathrm{sin(30° - 5\theta)} = \mathrm{sin(30°)cos(5\theta) - sin(5\theta)cos(30°)}$

$\mathrm{sin(5\theta)} = \mathrm{\frac{1}{2}cos(5\theta) - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}sin(5\theta)}, \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \mathrm{sin(5\theta)} = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{cos(5\theta)}$

$\left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \mathrm{sin(2\theta + 3\theta)} = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{cos(2\theta + 3\theta)}$

Use angle addition identities again:

$\mathrm{ \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) \left( \left( 2sin(\theta)cos(\theta) \right) \left( 4cos^{3}(\theta)-3cos(\theta) \right) + \left( 3sin(\theta) - 4sin^{3}(\theta) \right) \left( 1 - sin^{2}(\theta) \right) \right)} = $ ... [similarly expanded] ...

Want to solve for $\mathrm{sin(\theta)}$, at least initially. Convert all cosines possible to sines and simplify:

... [a lot of algebra, probably with mistakes] ...

$\mathrm{\left( 1 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)\left( 16sin^{5}(\theta) - 24sin^{3}(\theta) + 5sin(\theta) \right)} = \mathrm{\frac{1}{2}cos(\theta) \left( 4sin^{4}(\theta) - 2sin^{2}(\theta) + 1 \right)} = \mathrm{\frac{1}{2} \left(\pm \sqrt{1 - sin^{2}(\theta)} \right) \left( 4sin^{4}(\theta) - 2sin^{2}(\theta) + 1 \right)}$

And at this point, this is not analytically solvable for sin($\theta$) (as far as I can tell). I got the feeling soon into this derivation that this was not the right approach, but I wanted to see if this would work for any angle $\theta$.

I found [a geometric proof for sin(3°)](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/college.math.j.47.5.322.pdf) which also relies on a geometric proof for sin(18°), but I was hoping to do this without polygonal constructions.

---

## TL;DR:

Did I make a mistake in my logic (other than assuming $\mathrm{sin(\theta)}$ was determinable this way)? How can I algebraically and exactly calculate the value of a trig function applied to any non-transcendental angle value?

Comment: You can find sines and cosines of 72° and 60° by special tricks, then find them for 12° by the difference of angles formula, and finally 6° and 3° by repeatedly solving the quadratic equation of the double angle formula. This is, roughly, an algebraic variant of how Prolemy constructed his table of chords in the Almagest (he actually used geometric analogs instead), see [Aaboe, Episodes From the Early History of Astronomy, 4.3](https://books.google.com/books/about/Episodes_From_the_Early_History_of_Astro.html?id=yK8Tp0izorMC).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_values

Comment: The rational angle $40^\circ=360^\circ/9$ (the exterior angle of a regular enneagon) is not constructible; it requires solutions of cubic equations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection

Answer (score 1):

To make the story short, we know that
$$\sin (18 {}^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \cos (18 {}^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt 5}}{4} $$ 
$$\sin (15 {}^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \cos (15 {}^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
$$\sin (3 {}^{\circ})=\sin ((18-15) {}^{\circ})=\sin (18 {}^{\circ})\cos (15 {}^{\circ})-\sin (15 {}^{\circ})\cos (18 {}^{\circ})$$
$$\sin (3 {}^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)-2
   \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{16} $$

Do the same for the cosine.